# Using transformers-cli on Windows?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I can't figure out how to use transformers-cli on Windows. I got it working on Google Colab, and am using it in the meantime.

[EDIT]

Here's the process that I'm going through, what I expect, and what is happening:

**I'm on a Windows System (brackets are the exact commands I'm typing into CMD)**

1. I install transformers==2.8.0 (pip install transformers==2.8.0)
2. I try to run transformers-cli as explained on Huggingface's website (transformers-cli) https://huggingface.co/transformers/model_sharing.html

**I get:**

```
'transformers-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

I don't know if I have to add some directory to my PATH or perhaps the CLI isn't available on Windows?

**I repeat the exact same process on Google Colab, and it works as expected. I get:**

```
usage: transformers-cli <command> [<args>]

positional arguments:
  {convert,download,env,run,serve,login,whoami,logout,s3,upload}
                        transformers-cli command helpers
    convert             CLI tool to run convert model from original author
                        checkpoints to Transformers PyTorch checkpoints.
    run                 Run a pipeline through the CLI
    serve               CLI tool to run inference requests through REST and
                        GraphQL endpoints.
    login               Log in using the same credentials as on huggingface.co
    whoami              Find out which huggingface.co account you are logged
                        in as.
    logout              Log out
    s3                  {ls, rm} Commands to interact with the files you
                        upload on S3.
    upload              Upload a model to S3.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of what you were trying to do exactly. Also include a version of your `transformers` package.

Comment: @dennlinger I've updated the question. I hope that helps?

Answer (score 3):

All you have to do is to locate the script and launch it. It won't be added to the $PATH automatically. In my python interpreter installation on Windows 10 (not anaconda just python), it was installed in the `Scripts` folder of my python interpreter directory. You have to launch it with the python interpreter as windows, as far as I know, doesn't support Shebangs.

```
cd YOURPYTHONINTERPRETERDIRECTORY\Scripts
python.exe transformers-cli login
```

You can define a [macro](https://superuser.com/questions/560519/how-to-set-an-alias-in-windows-command-line) to shortcut transformers-cli.